# PowerBuilder problems with long, longlong, integers, dec, and decimal datatypes

Tags: types, decimal, powerbuilder

I am having problems with long, longlong, integers, dec, and decimal datatypes in PowerBuilder 12.5 Classic...
I did something like this and is giving me problems of datatypes;

```
// set variables for item price and the cash given by the customer

double price, cash

price=double(trim(sle_price.text))
cash=double(trim(sle_cash.text))



if cash="" then
    messagebox("","CASH")
    sle_cash.setfocus()
    return
end if

if  fare="" then
    messagebox("","SET FARE")
    sle_amount.setfocus()
    return
end if
double balance

balance=cash -price


 messagebox("",balance)

INSERT INTO cash_table  
         ( items.price   

  VALUES ( :price );
```

Comment: What problem are you experiencing?

Comment: Why you try to compare `double` with `string`?

Comment: it gives: Error c0011 incompatible types in expression: double, string

Comment: And, in general, telling us which line is throwing the error would help too (the error display shows the line number, and double-clicking on it jumps you to that line too), but Maximus already spotted it. Comparing the double variable cash to the string constant "" will throw this error (if cash="" then).

Comment: @Maximus IMHO you deserve the win; you called it before the problem description was complete!! Why not post an answer (instead of just a comment) so we can give credit where credit is due.

Answer (score 3):

From my comment

> Why you try to compare double with string?

Comparing different types are illegal. Correct example

```
if trim(sle_cash.text) = "" then
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are comparing `double cash` and `double fare` variables with `"" (empty string)` to find out if input fields are empty or not. Instead of that way, you can do something like this:

```
if trim(sle_cash.text)="" then
    messagebox("","CASH")
    sle_cash.setfocus()
    return
end if

if  trim(sle_fare.text)="" then
    messagebox("","SET FARE")
    sle_amount.setfocus()
    return
end if
```